# CI form validation for unique email in two table?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I want to check on form submit that email is unique in two tables "Student Registration" and "Staffs". I tried this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|xss_clean|trim|is_unique[student_registration.email]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|xss_clean|trim|is_unique[staffs.email]');
```

Problem is if email is not unique in student table but unique in staffs table it submit form successfully because last validation set it true. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can u provide some details?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|xss_clean|trim|is_unique[student_registration.email]|is_unique[staffs.email]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|callback_has_email[email]');
```

Call back function

```
 public function has_email($str)
        {

/*do your stuff check for email*/
            if (true)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('has_email', 'The %s field already register');
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
```